# Reported speech for "Let's go out for a walk."

Tags: phrase-usage, reported-speech

> She said to me, "Let's go out for a walk."

> She suggested [proposed] to me that **we** (should) go out for a
> walk.

([source](https://manabitimes.jp/english/2481))

Is the second sentence a correct reported speech version of the first sentence?

I suspect that **we** does not necessarily refer to "me" and "She".

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed version of reported speech works fine, even though the *we* is ambiguous. It could mean the (current) speaker, the one who’s reporting speech, and her **or** it could mean the (current) speaker and some other party whose identity is understood by the (current) addressee.

Comment: Unless the context made it clear that other people were involved, I think most readers would assume that the speaker meant 'you and I'.